# Breaking ruby module across several files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

I have a ruby module that is supposed to wrap up quite a few classes

```
module A
  class First
    #somemethods
  end

  class Second
    #somemethods
  end

  class Third
    #somemethods
  end
end
```

What i would like to do in rails is to break up these classes into several files what might be the best practice to split this huge module into several relevant files?

Answer (score 48):

One approach would be to come up with directory structure like this:

```
(root dir)
├── a
│   ├── first.rb
│   ├── second.rb
│   └── third.rb
└── a.rb
```

Files contents:

```
# a.rb
require_relative './a/first.rb'
require_relative './a/second.rb'
require_relative './a/third.rb'

module A
end


# a/first.rb
module A
  class First
    # ...
  end
end


# a/second.rb
module A
  class Second
    # ...
  end
end


# a/third.rb
module A
  class Third
    # ...
  end
end
```