# How to move classes into their own file

Tags: ruby

I have a structure like this in file `foo.rb`:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    Bar.new
  end

  class Bar
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to extract the `Bar` class, and put it in a separate file, ideally in a folder. I'm struggling to extract the classes from the module into separate files. It is difficult to understand the difference between modules and classes, and where they should reside. I get the error `uninitialized constant` in my attempts.

Is there some naming convention to follow to make this work?

Comment: You probably just need to remember to `require 'bar'` at the top of your `foo.rb`.

Comment: Nope. File names are irrelevant to class names, and whether they are loaded unless you are using something special, such as a particular framework.

Answer (score 0):

At the interpreter level, modules are similar to classes. Following rails conventions, you would have a separate file called bar.rb and require it at the top of module foo.

bar.rb:

```
class Bar
end
```

foo.rb:

```
require 'bar'

module Foo

  def self.bar
     Bar.new
  end

end
```

If you want to put the bar file in a different folder, see info about require_relative which allows you to require a file from a path relative to the current file.

Comment: And what if I want to keep the namespace Foo?

Comment: Do you mean split up a module into multiple files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035057/breaking-ruby-module-across-several-files if you find your answer there, please mark this question as a duplicate.